# Invalid argument supplied for foreach error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my code in codeigniter

**IN MODEL**

```
    $where = "is_display ='Yes' AND start_date < '{$current_time}' AND end_date >              
             '{$current_time}' AND status = 'Live' AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (emts_auction)                           
             WHERE is_display = 'Yes' AND quantity =1 AND sold_qty >0    
             AND last_auc_ending_time < '{$current_time}')";

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('auction');
    $this->db->where($where);       
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data = $query->result();
        $query->free_result();
        return $data;
```

**IN VIEW**

```
  <?php foreach($auction_view as $auction)
       {
       echo $auction->name;
       echo $auction->price;
       echo $auction->bid_fee;
       }
      ?>
```

Comment: Check result of query, may be using var_dump() or print_r()

Comment: `$auction_view` is not an array at all.

Comment: it means no records are matching and result is null

Comment: i think you should give your table schema and ask how to fetch the data from table with your requirements ;

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `$auction_view`  if it is an array or not , before using foreach on it. Your result may be false since your database query may fail, or returned no result. try to check if it by using `is_array` or you could do check if it is not empty `if( !empty($auction_view) )`

```
if (is_array($auction_view))
{
   foreach($auction_view as $auction)
       {
       echo $auction->name;
       echo $auction->price;
       echo $auction->bid_fee;
       }
}
```

Comment: $auction_view is an array which i've defined in controller,,,,,i guess my database query is wrong in where part and is returning null!!! anyway thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

**In model**

```
where = "is_display ='Yes' AND start_date < '{$current_time}' AND end_date >              
'{$current_time}' AND status = 'Live' AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (emts_auction)                           
WHERE is_display = 'Yes' AND quantity =1 AND sold_qty >0    
AND last_auc_ending_time < '{$current_time}')";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('auction');
$this->db->where($where);       
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
$query = $this->db->get();
if($quer->num_rows() < 0){return  $query->result();
}
return  '';
```

**In view**

```
<?php 
if(!empty($auction_view)){
foreach($auction_view as $auction)
{
echo $auction->name;
echo $auction->price;
echo $auction->bid_fee;
}
}
?>
```